# Is there a way of sending object containing a list of other objects using angular post command

Tags: c#, angular

I have an object that I send to my c# server using `post` angular command.
Everything works fine if that object does not contain a array of another object type (Schedule).
Any idea how can I send using `post` method `UpdateRequest` containing array of other objects.

Angular side of code:

```
export class Account {
id: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
schedules: Schedule[] = [];
}

export class Schedule {
id: string;
date: Date;
availability: boolean;

constructor(init?:Partial<Schedule>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
}
}

return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, account)
.pipe(map((account: any) => {
    // update the current account if it was updated
    if (account.id === this.accountValue.id) {
    }
    return account;
}));
```

On the c# side the code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("{id:int}")]
public ActionResult<AccountResponse> Update(int id, [FromBody]UpdateRequest model)
{
  // function body
}
```

where `UpdateRequest` looks like the following:

```
public class UpdateRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Schedule[] Schedules { get; set; }
}
```

**1. Note - changed to work**

Intermediate class for Schedule:

```
public class UpdateScheduleRequest
    {

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Boolean Availability { get; set; }
    }
```

and UpdateRequest

```
public class UpdateRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public UpdateScheduleRequest[] Schedules { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think much better is create separate page for shedule, rather than update both schedule and account in one request, that`s will be a bounch of code

Comment: Then I face similar problem - how to send from angular client to c# server an array of Schedule object. At least I could not find any solution for sending an array to c# server on internet.

Comment: I'm using interfaces instead of classes and I can post an object that contains an array of objects. I'm not saying you should switch to interfaces, it should work also with classes, but I don't see where the problem is

Comment: @user19564787: what's the error exactly? The `Schedules` is empty?

Comment: The error is 'Bad Request'

Comment: I have provided intermediate class for Schedule called UpdateScheduleRequest without `Id` field. `Schedule` is database entity (declered as `public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; })` in the `DBContext` derrived class and has to contain an `Id field`. I have added this intermediate class in my original question. I don't know why but even with this UpdateScheduleRequest class if I add `Id` field I get error `Bad Request`. But it works fine without `Id` field - why?